Hilbert-Schmidt integral operator without second integrable kernel
From this webpage, we know that if $X$ is a measurable space ($\sigma$-algebra is omitted) and $\mu$ is the measure, $K(x,y) \in L_2(X\times X,\mu\times \mu)$, we can define the following operator from $L_2(X,\mu)$ to $L_2(X,\mu)$:
$$(Tf)(x) = \int_X K(x,y)f(y)\mu(dy).$$
Assume that the operator $T$ is self-adjoint, then we have the following decompositions:
$$(Tf)(x) = \sum_n \lambda_n \langle f,\phi_n\rangle\phi_n(x),$$
$$K(x,y) = \sum_{n}\lambda_n\phi_n(x)\phi_n(y),$$
where ${\phi_n}$ is the orthonormal system of eigenfunctions of $T$ and $\lambda_n$'s are eigenvalues of $T$.
My question is if $K(x,y) \notin L_2(X\times X,\mu\times \mu)$, i.e. $\int_X\int_X K^2(x,y) \mu(dx)\mu(dy) = \infty$, what can we say about the operator $T$?
Does it still have a set of orthonormal eigenfunctions and corresponding eigenvalues? And do we still have the decomposition?

In general as long as $T$ is a self-adjoint operator (possibly unbounded) you can consider its spetrum take the so-called "spetral decomposition". The spetrum is generalization to eigenvalues, elements to which can be but not necessarily eigenvalues.
Here is an example, let $m\in L^\infty(\mathbb R)$, the Fourier multiplier $Tf=(m\hat f)^\vee$ is given by $Tf(x)=\int_{\mathbb R} m(\xi)\hat f(\xi)e^{2\pi ix\xi}d\xi$ where $\hat f(\xi)=\int_\mathbb R f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\xi}dx$, both of which makes sense as generalized Riemann integrals.
In this case roughly speaking $T(e^{2\pi i(\cdot)\xi})=m(\xi)e^{2\pi i(\cdot)\xi}$ gives the "eigenfunctions", which are not in $L^2(\mathbb R)$ of course.

Thanks for your answer! Do you mean that the spectral decomposition also applies to self-adjoint operator which may not be compact? Because I think without the assumption that $K(x,y)$ is in $L_2$, the operator $T$ may not be compact.

@efsdfmo12 If $T$ is compact sure all the nonzero spectrum are eigenvalues. But you didn't mention the compactness of $T$ in the question I think.

I guess the compactness is implied by the assumption that $K(x,y)$ is in $L_2$? But when we do not assume this, then $T$ may not even be bounded, so it is also may not be compact. Is my understanding correct? @Liding Yao

Here as long as m is bounded the T is bounded in L^2. You can google Hilbert transform. The kernel is not even L1_loc
